# SQL Query Opening Balance Becomes Closing Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my first time using stackoverflow,

I have a query problem,
there are 4 tables (with left join)

filtered by year and period and also an account code.

This is the query :

```
select a.fyear,a.aperiod,c.trx_amt
,e.acct_cd,e.active_status

,ISNULL((select 
openingBalance=SUM(a.trx_amt)
from 
gl_pendjnls a
left join gl_jlhdr b on a.idxjlhdr = b.idx
left join v_acctperiod c on b.idxperiod = c.idx
right join v_gl_chart d on  a.idxcoa = d.idx

where c.fyear < = 2013 and c.aperiod < 10
and d.acct_cd = e.acct_cd
group by d.acct_cd
   ),0) as openingBalance

,ISNULL((select 
closingBalance=SUM(a.trx_amt) + c.trx_amt

from 
gl_pendjnls a
left join gl_jlhdr b on a.idxjlhdr = b.idx
left join v_acctperiod f on b.idxperiod = f.idx
left join v_gl_chart d on  a.idxcoa = d.idx

where f.fyear < = 2013 and f.aperiod < 10
and d.acct_cd = e.acct_cd
group by d.acct_cd
   ),0) as closingBalance

from v_acctperiod a
left join gl_jlhdr b on a.idx = b.idxperiod
left join gl_pendjnls c on b.idx = c.idxjlhdr
left join v_gl_chart e on c.idxcoa = e.idx
where e.active_status = 'Y'

and a.fyear = 2013 and a.aperiod = 10
and e.acct_cd = '111-01-201'
```

the result and the result that i want :

[image]

if i change the a.fyear to = 2013 and a.period = 11 and remove the e.acct_cd = '111-01-201'

there is no data,

all i want it has data, 
a new row that consist the acct_cd from the last period opening balance,
so the new row data consist only acct_cd from the last period opening balance, openingbalance = 0, closingbalance = opening balance the last period

is anybody can help?. i really appriciated for your attention.

Comment: the result picture that i make is wrong,

Comment: this is the right picture : http://i44.tinypic.com/oju9t.jpg

Comment: so what i mean is, the opening balance = closing balance from last period for the new row

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?